# How to fix camera drift in Horizon Zero Dawn (PC edition)

Tags: pc, horizon-zero-dawn

I've just started playing Horizon Zero Dawn on PC and I've noticed that the camera is laggy, it doesn't respond to my mouse movements fast enough. It is not the response time that's the problem, but it kinda has inertia. This is exacerbated when I move and strafe at the same time.

For example, if I move in a straight line and I'd like to look to the left while I keep running in the same direction then I'd press <kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd> (not just <kbd>W</kbd>) to be able to do that. This works as expected, but the camera keeps turning a little bit more after I stop moving my mouse and after doing this for an hour now I have nausea.

Is there a way to disable this camera "inertia" / moving feature? I expect my camera to only turn if I move the mouse and only while I'm moving the mouse. I get that this was supposed to add some cinematic effect (I guess), but it is ruining my gameplay.

Comment: I checked on the original PS4 version and this doesn't happen there.

Comment: Good to know, but it is not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this "mod" that centers the camera and stops it from drifting, just google  HZD_PC_Gamer_Camera, it's on GitHub by PixelRick, maybe this will help ...

Comment: Why not adding a link instead of explaining how to search for it?

Comment: https://github.com/PixelRick/HZD_PC_Gamer_Camera

Comment: **YES!** This fixed my game!